# Get case insensitive request header value

Tags: spring

From `HttpServletRequest.getHeader("name")` how can I get the value irrespective of case ...like somebody specifying **name** or **Name** etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the javadoc, the parameter is considered case insensitive:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29

So your example should already be good to go, catching both "name" and "Name".

Comment: That's strange, I just verified in my project: header "name" and "Name" are both resolved by using either of both parameters. I'm using servlet-ap 2.5 btw.